# Can I use DateFormat.is24HourFormat() with an application context?

Tags: java, android, android-context

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#is24HourFormat%28android.content.Context%29

I know that I can use this with an `Activity` context, but can I use this method with an `Application` context instead (so I don't have to pass in a `Context` variable to a method that utilizes this method?

Comment: If you look at the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/format/DateFormat.java) the method just reads the locale from context, so the application context will suffice.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Is there a way to tell absolutely from the source which one is needed in a given instance? (i.e. how did you know that the application context would suffice if you only need the locale)?

Comment: Both will return the same value if asked for locale. You only need to provide activity context when inflating widgets and resolving colors and drawables (on API >= 21), so color attributes can be resolved. In any other case application context is fine.

Comment: Thanks, @EugenPechanec. If you post as an answer, I will accept.